# Archive iOS app : no suitable records were found verify your bundle identifier is correct

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I am trying to archive an ios app in xcode but keep getting the following error message: [image]

I've correctly created an App ID [image]
and a provision profile :[image]
but the message keeps appearing whenever I want to validate the archive in xcode.
Does anyone knows whats wrong here?

Comment: Validation takes progress against iTC bundle containing the same appId. Have you created this bundle in iTC before trying to validate archived app? ie: sign in to iTunse Connect -> My Apps -> + -> Create Bundle...

Comment: When I press the "+" button in iTunes Connect --> My Apps, I only have the option "New iOS app". But I already made one.

Comment: If you had done that (for this bundle id) it might help to just wait a couple of hours. We'd had quite a lot of strange experiences with iTC in last two weeks.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 9):

This is a painful problem but easy to solve - below is a simple solution. I hope it helps:

**iTunes Connect:**

- In your browser, go to iTunes connect.
- Add your New App / edit your existing app.
- Go to App information.
- Check the Bundle ID name.
- If there is no bundle ID, make sure you create one.
- I used the WildCard bundle ID. That means, your complete bundle ID is likely to be com.organizationName.* and the suffix (exampleApp).

**Xcode:**

- Go to your Workspace / Project.
- Go to your project.
- Select the General Tab.
- Ensure the Bundle Identifier is the name you set in
  iTunes Connect. For example: com.organizationName.exampleApp

It seems you have to start the App Store submission process in iTunesConnect.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I have an app on App Store connect but I was getting that error. The problem was app has a limited access for users. Because of that I can not able to upload my app. You can edit your user access on App Store Connect - Your App - App Information - Edit User Access.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an application in Itunes Connect first, if you want to publish your app to the App Store.

After you created the app in Itunes Connect, it will be stated as **waiting for upload**. Itunes Connect is now able to validate your app.

From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH9-SW20):

> Xcode uploads the archive to iTunes Connect and iTunes Connect runs validation tests. If a dialog appears stating that no application record can be found, click Done, create an app record in iTunes Connect, and repeat these steps.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same error, except that the pointed bundle identifier was from a dependency I used in the main project which was odd.

Just in case someone else has the same issue, the solution is to add in `Info.plist` of your main project:     `<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>` having `APPL` value.

Comment: Very helpful. I had the exact same issue where the bundle ID of a dependency was appearing as invalid, even though my bundle ID was correct and configure on iTunes connect. I had accidentally deleted this key in the info.plist, leading to a frustrating issue, with a misleading error message.